# Powershell: Reading in a column from a .CSV file and then adding a specific string to the beginning and exporting again

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm attempting to write a script which will read in a CSV generated by querying AD for user information (that part is done) but then will allow me to add a string to the beginning of each value of a column in the CSV file and then export it.

For instance we have this CSV file:

> "displayname","Office"
>   Bob,7142
>   Janet,8923
>   SantaClaus,0912
>   NicCage,0823

I want to take each entry for "Office", add the string "BUG" before it and then export it back out. The modified CSV should look like:

> "displayname","Office"
>   Bob,BUG7142
>   Janet,BUG8923
>   SantaClaus,BUG0912
>   NicCage,BUG0823

At this point, I've been attempting to read in just the "Office" column and then displaying it with "Write-Host". The idea being that if I can do that then maybe I can create a new variable that would be something like:

```
$BUG = "BUG"
$NewVar = $BUG$Office
```

Which would hopefully look like the second CSV file. I am extremely new to powershell scripting.

The attempts I've made so far are these:

Attempt #1:

```
$UserList = Import-CSV C:\Users\username\CSV.csv
$UserList | ForEach-Object ($_.Office) { $UserList }
```

Attempt #2:

```
$projectName = import-csv  C:\Users\username\CSV.csv | % {$_.Office}
$BUG = "BUG"
$projectName | ForEach-Object ($_) {$projectName}
```

Attempt #3:

```
$UserList = Import-CSV C:\Users\username\CSV.csv
#ForEach ($Office in $Userlist) {
#Write-Host $UserList.Office
#}
```

Attempt #4:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\username\CSV.csv" -Header       ("displayname","Office","whenCreated","EmailAddress") | Select-Object Office | Export-CSV -Path C:\users\Username\test.csv
```

I have gotten it to read out just the Office numbers before using the ForEach-Object loop structure but then it never stops reading out the office numbers so that's unhelpful.

I think I'm going in the right direction, but I just can't figure out how to modify a column like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to extract the `Office` column, just pipe the full data set (all columns) to `ForEach-Object`, change the value of the `Office` property and pipe it back to `Export-Csv`:

```
$Prefix = "BUG"
Import-Csv .\file.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Office = $Prefix + $_.Office
    $_
} | Export-Csv .\file_modified.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hmm, I attempted to run your code (changing to the correct paths, obviously) but it gave me just a blank .CSV file. I also tried to pipe it to Write-Host instead of Export-CSV to see if it would show what I was doing but it didn't show anything...weirdly.

Comment: Hey, that worked! Awesome, thank you very much! If I may, though, I tried (just out of curiosity) to pipe $_.Office instead of all of $_ to Export-CSV and it did something weird, it only exported the first number of each of the office numbers...what you gave me is good so no need to answer, I was just curious.

Comment: @Redcoatwright Are your sure it didn't export the length of each `Office` string?

Comment: I get the following at the top of the output file `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`